# Will we have absolute convergence in this case?, series in finite measure-space.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Assume that you are on a finite measure space $(\Omega,
>  \mathcal{A},\mu)$. Assume that the series $\sum\limits_{i=0}^Mf_n(x)$,
>   converges in $L^2$ to $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty f_n(x)$.
>
> $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ is just a notation for the $L^2$
>   object. I do not know if the sum makes sense in a pointwise way, it is
>   just the $L^2$ limit of the series above.
>
> Since the measure space is finite, we also know that all our objects
>   are in $L^1$ aswell, and that the convergence is in $L^1$ aswell.
>
> We then can show that as a sequence of real numbers
>   $\sum\limits_{i=0}^M\int_\Omega f_n(x)d\mu\rightarrow\int_\Omega
> \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty f_n(x)d\mu$. This follows since
>    $|\sum\limits_{i=0}^M\int_\Omega f_n(x)d\mu-\int_\Omega
> \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty f_n(x)d\mu|=|\int_\Omega[\sum\limits_{i=0}^M
>  f_n(x)d\mu-\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty f_n(x)]d\mu|$
>
> $\le\int_\Omega|\sum\limits_{i=0}^M
> f_n(x)d\mu-\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty f_n(x)|d\mu$. And then we use the
>   $L^1$ convergence.
>
> So in this case, it makes sense to talk about the convergence of
>   $\sum\limits_{i=0}^M\int_\Omega f_n(x)d\mu$ as a sequence of real
>   numbers.

But do we know if $\sum\limits_{i=0}^M\int_\Omega f_n(x)d\mu$ converges absolutely?, that is does: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^M|\int_\Omega f_n(x)d\mu|$ converge? And does the larger sum $\sum\limits_{i=0}^M\int_\Omega |f_n(x)|d\mu$ converge? Or are there counter-examples that show that this may not be the case?

Comment: What if you took $f_n=(-1)^n/n$ on $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you very much, that counter-example works.